# Can not find xml layout file in libgdx project

Tags: android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api, libgdx

I am working on a project in Android Studio. I was following a tutorial for Facebook Login for Android (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).

And To add the Facebook Login button, first, it had to be added in layout XML file with the full class name, `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`. But I can't find it anywhere. I even tried with Double shift shortcut, still no success.

Am I doing something wrong? If yes, please guide me in right direction or if there is another alternative approach to add facebook login button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is specifically for Andoid platform. You need to login with code and interact with `core module` using [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) but this is for Android only.

As we know LibGDX is cross platform game development framework so we have to write facebook specific code on all other platform.

Good news is someone already done for you, you've to use only with `Apache License 2.0`. Use [gdx-facebook](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook), A libGDX extension providing cross-platform support for Facebook Graph API.

Comment: that's perfect. But what if I created the only Android project in libgdx, is there any way we can edit and make changes in XML layout file? OR is this file is already been decoded in any other file?

Comment: `.xml` used to define the actual User interface of your application with model and controller but libgdx give you a view for manipulation from core module so you've to work on core module in anyway(if you want other platform or not). if not interested in other platform write code in android for view and his model and interact with core module using interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

- LibGdx is cross platform game development platform and all supported platform under libGDX is not supporting .xml file. So you have 2 way:

(1) Using interface you can easily integrate facebook

(2) Use LibGDX's Facebook supported graph API.[TomGril-LibGDX - facebook](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook)